# C: Extracting a specific set of bits? Need help explaining a particular example

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Question:

> A device is connected to a computer that can return various
>   temperatures related to the weather. The GetTemps function returns the
>   daily high temperature in bits 20–29, the daily low temperature in
>   bits 10–19, and the current temperature in bits 0–9, all as 10-bit
>   integers. In the following program fragment, lines 8 and 9 are
>   incomplete. They should store the high temperature in highTemp and the
>   current temperature in currTemp, so that these temperatures can be
>   printed in line 10. Please complete lines 8 and 9, and implement code
>   efficiently

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Line 1
// Line 2
int GetTemps(void);
// Line 3
// Line 4
int main( ) {
    // Line 5
    int w, highTemp, currTemp;
    // Line 6
    w = getTemps( );
    // Line 7
    highTemp = <QUESTION 1>
    // Line 8
    currTemp = <QUESTION 2>
    // Line 9
    printf ( "High: %d\nCurrent: %d\n", highTemp, currTemp)
    // Line 10
    return 0;
}
```

The answers are

```
highTemp = w>>20
currtemp = w<<20
```

> The correct right shift (for highTemp) and bitmask (for lowTemp)
>   operations.

As given by my class TA

Can someone explain this answer to me? I think I understand how hightemp is `w>>20`, but if `w` is a 30-bit `int[30...0]` then wouldn't a bitshift to the left push bits 10 to 0 to the left and effectively multiply it by 2^20? That seems too large to me.

Edit: The exact answer:
[image]

Comment: Your prof actually thinks `w << 20` is the right answer? As you say, it would produce an out of range value. Maybe he meant `w << 20 >> 20`?

Comment: Well, currTemp should be `w & 0x03FF`.

Comment: By the way, the first answer is right only if some assumptions valid, like that the bits 30, 31 are zero. Otherwise it will be signed shift (ones will be shifted in from the left)

Comment: Yes, that's what he gave. I added the explanation he gave for it.

Comment: So the bitmask is in my first comment, not the shift you are giving. You have misunderstood your prof in some point or he got confused.

Comment: Excuse me, sorry, it was actually a TA that posted it. But I've posted the exact answer that was given.

Comment: Well, it's just wrong. Bit Masking is done by logical AND (OR for the other type), not shifting. Semicolons are missing as well.

Comment: I see. Thanks. For the bit mask w&0x03FF, are the rest of bits, i.e. bits 14 through 30, just assumed to be masked? And how can I perform this operation in C?

Comment: `currTemp = w & 0x03FF;` 0x03FF is represented in binary as 10 (ten) ones, so doing a bitwise AND with any number will preserve the values of the lower 10 bits, while setting the others to zeros. Not 14 through 30, but 11 through 31

Comment: @Eugene Sh.:  `currTemp = w & 0x03FF;` will not preserve the sign if the temperature is negative.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Right. If we assume that the numbers can be negative and given in two's complement it should augmented. Bitmasking only will not work here.

Comment: @EugeneSh.:  Arithmetic right shift should do the right thing, regardless of the convention used for representing negative numbers.  It doesn't have to be two's complement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your TA's answer is wrong.  Here's how to solve the problem.

When several fields are packed into a single value, it's safest to isolate the bits you want first (by masking).  For example, given that the high temp is in bits 20-29, we need a mask to isolate those bits.

```
const int high_mask = 0x3FF00000;  // 10-bit integer in bits 20-29
const int high_bits = w & high_mask;  // select the bits we care about
```

To convert that to a temperature, we need to shift the result so that bit 20 is int bit 0.

```
const int high_temp = high_bits >> 20;  // shift them "down"
```

But this is not entirely right!  We haven't accounted for negative temperatures.  An arithmetic right-shift will preserve the sign of the value, but we've zero-ed out the high bits (of the 32-bit integer).  Even if we hadn't masked those bits out, the problem doesn't say what values are in those top bits, so we shouldn't make assumptions.

The easiest way to account for the sign is to first shift left, so that our top bit is in the top position.  Then, we when shift right, the processor will do the appropriate sign extension.  Assuming `int`s are 32 bits ...

```
const int high_temp = (high_bits << 3) >> 23;  // shift down, preserving the sign
```

Note that the right shift value must account for the left shift we did first.

(Technically, if we shift to lop off the top bits and then shift the other way to lop off the lowest bits, the masking is no longer necessary, but conceptually, it can help with comprehension.)

Also note that precedence with bit-wise operators can be surprising.  So if you try to combine these steps into a single expression, you'll likely have to add some parentheses.

A similar process can extract the current temperature (and any int value embedded in a larger integral type).  You just have to tweak the constants.